# How to save and fetch image into/from MySQL database using spring rest and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

Help me to create an app using react and spring rest to store and fetch images from MySQL database

Comment: I assume you are using Spring Data, correct?  If so I have a solution for you.   Let me know.

Comment: Yes, please....

Comment: @PaulWarren Yes

Comment: Aopologies for the delay.  I posted a potential solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Spring Content, a community project, that provides a Spring Data like Java and REST API for content; i.e. files, images, and videos.  It provides several interfaces for managing content either directly, or through association with Spring Data entities.  With several modules for supporting different types of storage including JPA for storing content as BLOBs.  Also with extension APIs for versioning, rendering content into different formats and full-text search.

As you have Spring Boot it is pretty easy to add to your project.

> pom.xml

```
   <!-- other dependencies -->
   ...

   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-jpa-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.M2</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.M2</version>
   </dependency>
```

> YourEntity.java

```
public class YourEntity {
   
   ... existing fields...
   
   @ContentId
   private UUID contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private Long contentLen;

   @MimeType
   private String mimeType;
}
```

> ImageContentStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path = "images")
public interface ImageContentStore extends ContentStore<YourEntity, UUID> {
}
```

This is all you need to do to configure your application with REST Endpoints for managing content associated with YourEntity in a database.

How this actually works is very much like Spring Data.  When your application starts Spring Content will see the `spring-content-jpa` dependency, know that you want to store content on your filesystem and inject a JPA-based implementation for the `ImageContentStore` interface.  It will also see the `spring-content-rest` dependency and inject a Controlller (i.e. REST endpoints) that use to the `ImageContentStore` interface.  Therefore, you don't have to code up any of this yourself.

On the client-side use, in your reactjs code, you can then consume these REST api as you would any other Rest API.  I am not a react person so I'll give curl examples:

So...

`curl -X POST /yourEntities/{yourEntityId} -F 'file=@path/to/local/file.jpg'`

will store the content `path/to/local/file.jpg` in the database and associate it with YourEntity whose id is `yourEntityId`.

`curl /yourEntities/{yourEntityId} -H 'Accept: image/jpg'`

will fetch it again and so on...

The REST API supports full CRUD (and video streaming too)

There getting started guides and videos [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  The  reference guide for Spring Content JPA is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/jpa-index.html).

HTH

Comment: Hi @Paul. I tried your suggestion. And went with the guide. My storage is mysql. Tested with one file - storage is working. Unfortunately, getContent() only return "content". Scratching my head on what's going on here.

Comment: That sounds very much like you have not enabled the right blob storage mode for your mysql connection.  MySQL has a couple of different implementations for handling BLOBs.  Spring Content supports the locator emulation mode as it streams correctly so you have to specify `emulateLocators=true` on your jdbc connection string.  See the MySQL subsection under 2.1.1 Content Streaming in the JPA guide (https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/1.1.0.M5/jpa-index.html#_jpa_content_stores)

Comment: Spot on. Thanks a lot, @Paul. How could I miss that clear and precise statement ....

Comment: The docs aren't great IMO and it is easy to miss.  I have been meaning to see if it is possible to add å validation or a warning to the jdbc string.  Anyway, thanks for reaching out.  Glad I could help.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, it's clear and precise. 100% my fault. Cheers!